# Developing Functions to Make New Dataframes in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to develop a function that will take data, see if it matches a value in a category (e.g., 'Accident', and if so, develop a new dataframe using the following code.

```
cat.df <- function(i) {
   sdb.i <- sdb %>%
   filter(Category == i) %>%
   group_by(Year) %>%
   summarise(count = n()}
```

The name of the dataframe should be sdb.i, where i is the name of the category (e.g., 'Accident'). Unfortunately, I cannot get it to work. I'm notoriously bad with functions and would love some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are after so I am making a guess. 
First of all, your function `cat.df` misses a closing bracket so it would not run.
I think it is good practice to pass all objects as parameters to a function. In my example I use the `iris` dataset so I pass this explicitly to the function.

You cannot change the name of a data frame in the way you describe. I offer two alternatives: if the count of your categories is limited you can just create separate names for each object. it you have many categories, best to combine all result objects into a list.

```
library(dplyr)

data(iris)

cat.df <- function(data, i) {
  data <- data %>%
    filter(Species== i) %>%
    group_by(Petal.Width) %>%
    summarise(count = n())
  return(data)
}

result.setosa <- cat.df(iris, "setosa") # unique name

Species <- sort(unique(iris$Species))
results_list <- lapply(Species, function(x) cat.df(iris, x)) # combine all df's into a list
names(results_list) <- Species # name the list elements
```

You can then get the list elements as e.g. `results_list$setosa` or `results_list[[1]]`.